# How to use Connectivity manager.NetworkCallback to get network type

Tags: java, android, connection

In my project I want to show the type of connection that is used.
For example when the user enables wifi and opens the app 
The toast with WiFi enabled is shown if used mobile data then another toast should be shown.

I used the following code to show the type but I found that `TYPE_WIFI` & `TYPE_MOBILE` is deprecated and suggests to use the `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback();`. So I'm confused how to use it

Just help me know how to do that

Here is my code snippet

```
public void CheckConnection(){

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(null!=activeNetwork){

        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected with Wi-Fi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected with Cellular Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet connection Detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

Second create Broadcast receiver where you will get all this changes :

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
 }
```

And don't forgot to add your broadcast into mainfest :

```
  <receiver
        android:name="YOUR PACKAGE NAME"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also alternative of getType() : in kotlin

```
    private fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    var result = false
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
        result = when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        connectivityManager.run {
            connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                result = when (type) {
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                    else -> false
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Alternative of getType() in java :

```
 public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) { 
boolean result = false; 
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                result = true;
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            // connected to the internet
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                result = true;
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: But the gettype(); type_wifi and type_mobile is deprecated right that why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Our both code snippets do the same work and those methods are deprecated. I need the new feature

Comment: Can you please give me a java code I'm unaware of kotlin

Comment: Code updated in java let me know if still any issue and upvote and accept if this help  you.